# How do I restart my code after it is exited?

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

I have some code that "turns off" (exits) when told to. But I want it to not just turn off, I want it to "reboot", like the restart computer button: turn off, turn back on, reload everything. This is so the bot can update if an update is ready.

I thought of perhaps another file constantly checking if my `main.js` is running, and perhaps rebooting `main.js` if it's off.

But I do not know how to do this. I've tried Googling, but I found no answers for JavaScript.

Comment: You can run your node server using forever (npm package) and init scripts based on, for more information check this -> http://blog.podrezo.com/init-d-startupshutdown-script-for-node-js-applications-via-forever/.

Comment: I know, and I use discord.js for my bot, but that's besides the point isn't it?
node.js has an event listener `process.on("exit")` but I cant figure out how to reboot.

Comment: A process cannot reboot itself. It exits. You can simulate a reboot by spawning a child process before exiting (nodejs solution). Or just use any tool of your system to kill/run your process (don't use nodejs for this).

Answer (score 1):

I use nodemon to restart my code in development. In production I've been told that forever.js can accomplish the same task. You can configure it to listen for file changes and then restart your server. A better option, if you want it to be event driven, is probably to write a shell script that can be called by bot to restart the service.

Something like:

```
!#/bin/bash
killall node
node /path/to/server/index.js
```

This will restart your server from the system. Note that this is for Linux. Other OS's will have different commands potentially, especially non-Unix like systems.